# Sortable admin columns by 0.00 number

Tags: admin, dashboard, columns

I have a custom admin column I want to make sortable.

All the functionality is in place, but when I sort I get this order:

[image]

I expect this to be in the order: 1.69, 1, 0.5

The code for the echo is:

```
        if ( 'my_col' !== $column_name ) {
            return;
        }
        $field_data = get_post_meta($post_id, '_field_data', true);
        echo $increase_per_post;
```

I have tried `intval`, but those come out as 1 or 0

```
echo intval($field_data);
```

Comment: think simple :) I am giving you answer here. hope it will work
echo number_format($field_data, 2, '.', '');

Comment: Sorry - this still sorts in the original order in my question, the only change I can see is 0.5 becomes 0.50 and 1 becomes 1.00

Comment: did you see this?  it's helped me in the past: https://wpdreamer.com/2014/04/how-to-make-your-wordpress-admin-columns-sortable/